# error code registration page

Tags: mysql-error-1045

This code is to a registration page looks great, but again I get an error message after you typed the following code (below is the error message).

I can not understand what is the error and how it should be the correct code?

Codice mysql per fare dei test (aggiungiamo un utente)
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `online`, `email`, `active`, `rtime`) VALUES
(1, ‘testing’, ‘testing’, 0, ‘fake@noemail.co.uk’, 0, 0);

Answer (score 0):

code looks well.
Try to check that your root user have all the rights and password correct for your host.
as far as i can understand you are running with user root.

go to config file and check for user. If you are using phpmyadmin then you can check it in Privileges tab that your user have privileges to access